# bashrc substitute in Windows for making auto execution of CMD commands in each bootstrapping?

Tags: linux, windows-10, command-line, cmd.exe, bashrc

I want that each time I start the Windows CMD, a certain command will run.

In Nix systems like Ubuntu or Centos, I would just add the desired command to /etc/bash.bashrc or /home/USERNAME/.bashrc ...

Is there a bashrc substitute in Windows?

I would love to edit this file and add my desired command there, so that in each bootstrapping of CMD, it will run first and foremost!

Comment: There is an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17405182/5164855). Alternatively, you can create a short-cut which launches `cmd` with a `/k` command. In either case you specify a batch file of your choice.

Comment: Switch to Powershell (It will be the default soon, might as well switch now).  In Powershell, you can setup a Profile.ps1 file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `cmd /?`:

```
If /D was NOT specified on the command line, then when CMD.EXE starts, it
looks for the following REG_SZ/REG_EXPAND_SZ registry variables, and if
either or both are present, they are executed first.

    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun

        and/or

    HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try `Cmder`.

`/cmder/config/user-startup.cmd` is the equivalent of `.bashrc`.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.